# y-axis labels don't get displayed properly with Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I've a problem with displaying the y-axis labels properly with plotly.

This is my index:

```
index = ['2015-11','2015-12','2016-01','2016-02','2016-03','2016-04','2016-05',
         '2016-06','2016-07','2016-08','2016-09','2016-10','2016-11']
```

the data

```
data = [[0.115, 0.077, 0.0, 0.038, 0.0, 0.038, 0.038, 0.077, 0.0, 0.077, 0.077, 0.038],
  [0.073, 0.055, 0.083, 0.055, 0.018, 0.055, 0.073, 0.037, 0.028, 0.037, 0.009, 0.0],
  [0.099, 0.027, 0.036, 0.045, 0.063, 0.153, 0.027, 0.045, 0.063, 0.027, 0.0, 0.0],
  [0.076, 0.038, 0.053, 0.061, 0.098, 0.068, 0.038, 0.061, 0.023, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
  [0.142, 0.062, 0.027, 0.08, 0.097, 0.044, 0.071, 0.027, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
  [0.169, 0.026, 0.026, 0.026, 0.013, 0.013, 0.091, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
  [0.138, 0.121, 0.052, 0.017, 0.034, 0.017, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
  [0.297, 0.081, 0.054, 0.054, 0.054, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
  [0.095, 0.016, 0.024, 0.04, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
  [0.102, 0.023, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
  [0.054, 0.027, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
  [0.087, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

I create a heatmap with following code:

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
from plotly.offline import iplot
import re

cols = range(12)
index = index
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = cols)
df.index = index

x = df.columns.tolist()
y = df.index.tolist()
z = df.values

annotation_text = np.char.mod('%.0f%%', df*100).tolist()
annotation_text = [[re.sub('^0%$','', x) for x in l] for l in annotation_text]


colorscale=[[0.0, 'rgb(248, 248, 255)'], 
            [0.04, 'rgb(224, 228, 236)'], 
            [0.08, 'rgb(196, 210, 226)'], 
            [0.12, 'rgb(158, 178, 226)'],
            [0.16, 'rgb(134, 158, 227)'],
            [0.2, 'rgb(122, 146, 227)'],
            [1.0, 'rgb(65, 105, 225)'],
            ]


fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(z, x=x, y=y, colorscale= colorscale,
                                  annotation_text = annotation_text)

fig.layout.yaxis.autorange = 'reversed'
offline.iplot(fig, filename='annotated_heatmap_color.html')
```

Which produces the correct heatmap but with the y-axis labels missing
[image]

When I change the index to shorter values like `'5-11'` with

```
index = [x[3:] for x in index]
```

the labels show up.
[image]
 I don't understand the logic behind that and would like to know how to fix it.

Comment: You have some strange stuff in your example code that throws errors. Namely `index = index` and `df.index = index`. I deleted those lines so I can run your code and mine has the expected behavior with both axes labeled.

Comment: The index=index really doesn't make sense. İt's there because I renamed some stuff for Stackoverflow and forgot to delete that line. But df.index=index should be ok. İf you delete it, you don't get the desired index for the df and it should not display it at all- just integers on the y axis. My code didnt throw any errors on my mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plotly.py uses plotly.js under the hood, which is transforming your date strings to a numerical date format and misplacing them on your non numerical axis.

To explicit a categorical axis you just have to add:

```
fig.layout.yaxis.type = 'category'
```

Comment: Your solution worked so far, thank you very much. What is still not clear to me is why the chart displays `'5-11'`but not `'2015-11'`. This seems to be related to the length of the name.

Comment: it's just that `'2015-11'` is detected automatically as a date, whereas `'5-11'` is not so clear.